# Flexbox: Sections in 3 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

***I am trying to make 3 columns for the section but justify-content- space between doesn't work***

```css
.wrapper{display:flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    outline: solid;
    flex-basis: 1 1 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 2em auto;
        width: 50em;
        }

img{width:50em;}


section{display:flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-basis: 0 1 auto;
    outline:solid; 
    width: 20em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em;}
/* i need help with section pls*/
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Experience at DePaul CDM</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ux.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
         <h1>
             <span>DePaul University</span>
             <img src="" alt="DePaul Tree">
             <span>College of Computing and Digital Media</span>
         </h1>
    </header>
    <article class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Learning User Experience at DePaul CDM</h1>
            <figure><img src="680875765.webp" alt="User Experience at CDM"> </figure>
        </article>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h2>Bachelors of Science User Experience Design</h2>
            <p>The <i>Bachelor of Science in User Experience Design (UXD)</i> prepares students for the expanding fields
                of user experience and interaction design. The program integrates visual design, code, and user
                research. Concepts and skills involved include design principles, prototyping, and usability testing.
                Students will learn how to analyze, design, develop, and evaluate effective computer interfaces to
                provide better user experiences.
            </p>

            <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/BS-In-User-Experience-Design.aspx">Learn More</a>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Masters of Science Human-Computer Interaction</h2>
            <p>The <i>Master of Science in Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)</i> prepares students to ideate, design,
                implement and evaluate information and communication technologies (ICTs) so they are useful and usable
                for end users. This interdisciplinary degree integrates concepts and methods from computer science,
                graphic design and the social sciences. Drawing upon these concepts and methods, students learn
                user-centered and participatory design approaches as they create ICTs, including dynamic websites,
                mobile apps and desktop applications. Particular emphasis is given to ICT evaluation, exploratory user
                research, information architecture, interaction design and prototype development. </p>

            <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/MA-In-Experience-Design.aspx">Learn
                More</a>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Masters of ArtsExperience Design></h2>
            <p>The <i>Master of Arts in Experience Design</i> prepares students in the practice of designing products,
                processes, services, events and environments with a focus placed on the quality of the user experience
                and culturally relevant solutions. It is ideal for students seeking to learn the design methods that
                will enable them to address a range of problems across disciplines through the design of solutions that
                integrate mobile technologies, interactive systems, media, social practices and face-to-face
                interactions. Graduates will be prepared to produce diverse work that spans software development, user
                research, products, systems, services and games. </p>

            <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/PhD-Human-Centered-Design.aspx">Learn More</a>
        </section>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* nth child select first header */
header h1 span:nth-child(1){
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

header h1 span{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

header h1 img{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/*tips for using a flex box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 
  1. flexbox should always be set within parent element
  2. always make sure the element has a valid width and height
  3. after setting display to flex, you can set flex-direction for either row or column
  4. justify-content will adjust alignment
  5. align-items: center, will center content vertically
  6. text-align: center, will adjust text to the center of the parent element
*/

.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper h1{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper figure,
.wrapper figure img{
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

.section-wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header h1{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

section{
  width: 33vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

section p{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

section a{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
<header>
  <h1>
    <span>DePaul University</span>
    <img src="" alt="DePaul Tree"><br />
    <span>College of Computing and Digital Media</span><br /><br />
  </h1>
</header>
<article class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <br />
    <h1>Learning User Experience at DePaul CDM</h1>
    <br />
    <figure><img src="680875765.webp" alt="User Experience at CDM"> </figure>
  </header>
</article>

<div class="section-wrapper">
  <section>
    <h2>Bachelors of Science User Experience Design</h2>
    <p>The <i>Bachelor of Science in User Experience Design (UXD)</i> prepares students for the expanding fields
      of user experience and interaction design. The program integrates visual design, code, and user
      research. Concepts and skills involved include design principles, prototyping, and usability testing.
      Students will learn how to analyze, design, develop, and evaluate effective computer interfaces to
      provide better user experiences.
    </p>

    <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/BS-In-User-Experience-Design.aspx">Learn More</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Masters of Science Human-Computer Interaction</h2>
    <p>The <i>Master of Science in Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)</i> prepares students to ideate, design,
      implement and evaluate information and communication technologies (ICTs) so they are useful and usable
      for end users. This interdisciplinary degree integrates concepts and methods from computer science,
      graphic design and the social sciences. Drawing upon these concepts and methods, students learn
      user-centered and participatory design approaches as they create ICTs, including dynamic websites,
      mobile apps and desktop applications. Particular emphasis is given to ICT evaluation, exploratory user
      research, information architecture, interaction design and prototype development. </p>

    <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/MA-In-Experience-Design.aspx">Learn
      More</a>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Masters of ArtsExperience Design></h2>
    <p>The <i>Master of Arts in Experience Design</i> prepares students in the practice of designing products,
      processes, services, events and environments with a focus placed on the quality of the user experience
      and culturally relevant solutions. It is ideal for students seeking to learn the design methods that
      will enable them to address a range of problems across disciplines through the design of solutions that
      integrate mobile technologies, interactive systems, media, social practices and face-to-face
      interactions. Graduates will be prepared to produce diverse work that spans software development, user
      research, products, systems, services and games. </p>

    <a href="https://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/PhD-Human-Centered-Design.aspx">Learn More</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: even if this solves the anwser I consider this awnser as low quality. It misses any explanation of what you did and how you solve the issue. As such it gives no value to a learning effect or being easily reproduciable.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for remaindering, I am updating explanation :)

Comment: thank you, If the explanation is added I will revoke the downvote